# How to bootstrap a c# application?

Tags: .net, bootstrapping, asp.net-core-3.1

The application on which I am currently developing for my university project requires calling a method prior to its compiling. In order to achieve this, my idea is creating a small bootstrap program which will be executing the needed method and after that compiling and running the original app.

Therefore, I was wondering how can a bootstrapper for a .net core (3.1) application be created?

Comment: Executing a method pre-compile time? Not during runtime bootstrap of lets say a Webapi?

Comment: Runtime bootstrap also seems like a good option. Could you maybe explain a bit how this can be achieved?

Comment: In "Project Properties", tab "Build Events" you can specify a pre-build command to run. Of course this must be ready-to-run code, not some method inside the project *about to* compile (if that was what you meant)